# Rails ajax modal not closing after submit

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, modal-dialog

I ask for comments in a materialize-css modal view:

```
<% @contents.each do |content| %>
some form elements

<%=button_to('Comments', new_comment_path, :method => :get, params: {    :content_id => content.id }, :class=> 'modal-trigger', 'data-target'=>'modal4'+content.id.to_s) %>

<% end %>
```

modal=>

```
<div id="modal4<%=content.id%>"  class="modal modal-fixed-footer">
 <div class="modal-content">
  <%= form_for Comment.new, remote: true do |f| %>
    …
    …
    <%= f.submit 'Send’ %>

  <% end %>
```

CommentsController =>

```
def create
  @comment = Comment.new(comment_params)
end
```

The values are saved in the db:
Rendered comments/create.js.erb (0.0ms)

But: I can't get the modal close again after submit.

create.js =>

Tried with

```
$('#modal4').closeModal();
$('#modal4').modal('close');
$('modal4<%=@comment.content_id%>').closeModal();
$("modal4<%=@comment.content_id%>").modal('close');
```

But no success.

Comment: What is `content`? Do you have a `content_id` column in `comments` table?

Comment: And to evaluate ruby code inside JS, rename the file as `create.js.erb`.

Comment: @Arun => content_id is in..
Addition info:
As the modal is called inside a view categories and the create.js.erb is in the comments focus, it looks for me that $('#modal4').closeModal(); 
is not finding the path to the tag to close.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('modal4<%=@comment.content_id%>').modal('hide');
```

to close the modal.

For more, read http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-methods

Answer (score 0):

ok. the point was an entry in application.html =>

```
<base href='http://lvh.me:3000' />
```

Creating a => XMLHttpRequest cannot load

I end up successfully with...
route:

```
resource :contents do
  resources :comments, only: [:new, :create, :update]
end
```

Calling the modal

```
<%=button_to('Comment', '#', :method => :get, :class=> 'button button-primary button__slim send__feedback modal-trigger', 'data-target'=>'modal4'+content.id.to_s) %>
```

the from in the modal

```
<%= form_for(Comment.new, url: contents_comments_path, remote: true) do |f| %>
...
<%end%>
```

the comments_controller:

```
def create
  @comment = Comment.new(comment_params)
  @comment.update_attributes(rating: params[:rating])
end
```

and the create.js.erb

```
$('#modal4<%=@comment.content_id%>').closeModal();
```